# Embedded react component not rendered/loaded in html page. (webpack/babel)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to set up my first Webpack Babel React project.
Although the html code shows on various browsers (http://localhost:80), the embedded react component is not loaded. The following message can be read in the console 
*"Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
    at invariant (transformed.js:304)"*
[Click here to see error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRAbl.jpg)

Find below the different config and code files setting up this environment.

### ./app/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My first local App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='app'> </div>
  <h1> Testing </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

### ./app/index.js

```
 var React = require('react');
 var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
 var App = require('../components/App');

ReactDOM.render(
<App />,
document.getElementById('app')
);
```

### ./components/App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        console.log('Component has been constructed ')
    }
  render() {
     return (
      <div>
           <h1>This is a simple test</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, 
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "deploy":"npm run build && npm run git-commit && npm run git-push",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"   
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

### .babelrc

```
{presets:["react"]}
```

### webpack.config

```
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin ({  
                                                        template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
                                                        filename: 'index.html',
                                                        inject: 'body'
                                                    });
module.exports = {  
                    entry:  __dirname + '/app/index.js' , 
                    module: {loaders: [ {test:/\.js$/, exclude:/node_modules/, loader:'babel-loader' } ]},
                    output: {filename: 'transformed.js', path: __dirname + '/build'},
                    plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig],
                    resolve : { extensions: [".js", ".jsx"] }
                };
```

Thanks,

Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, 
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

in there twice. Could be other errors as well, but remove it from App.js and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, you are totally right. I just removed the ./app/index.js instance and it works.

Comment: @Bruce Great! Remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem, not just upvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

At first, remove second render in `<App />`, at second, change  `var App = require('../components/App');` to `import {App} from '../components/App';` And your error must gone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andrew. Your solution also solves the problem in a very clean way.

Comment: @Sebastian, Glad to help :)